# How to scrape data by searching for keyword and selecting dropdown using selenium in python?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape information using selenium in python from the below website which has search bars and drop down menu's. I want to scrape the results (Name, address, phone number) of the clinics from a specific region. For example in the "Ihr Standort" search bar the keywords as "Frankfurt, Germany" and in the Allgemeinmedizin dropdown menu selecting "Hausärzte" option. I am able to print the results by using search bar keywords "Frankfurt, Germany" but I am unable to write a code to select option for dropdown menu.

Can anyone help me how to also include the code to select "Hausärzte" option from Allgemeinmedizin dropdown and extract the results (Name, address, phone number) of the clinics.

Website:

```
https://www.kvwl.de/earzt/index.htm
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.kvwl.de/earzt/index.htm")
print(driver.title)

search_input = driver.find_element_by_id("doc-search-search-location")
search_input.send_keys("Bielefeld, Germany")

search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

print(driver.page_source)

driver.close()
```

Comment: you could mimic the page requests or take a chance and find a free API that returns lat lon for a location and pass that into a post request  to `https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/searchDocs` with  `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'} ;  data = {"Latitude":50.1109221, "Longitude":8.6821, "ExpertiseAreaStructureId":"12001_SID","PageSize":100}` - updating lat and lon appropriately. 100 is max result set. You can add page param e.g. "PageId":0

Comment: Couly you please provide me any link that has this techniques to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did a writeup for you using QHarr's suggestion to use the API. The API uses latitude/longitude input, so let's use `geopy` to retrieve those from the place name. We can then pass them together with the [code](https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/getExpertiseAreaStructure) for `Hausärzte` in the post request to the website's API and subsequently load the response as json with `json.loads`. I'm not sure how you want to process the data so for convenience I've loaded them in a `pandas` dataframe. Subsequently the dataframe runs a function on the column `Id` that passes the `Id` in a second API request to retrieve the details for that specific ID and concatenates them to the dataframe.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

location = "München, Germany"
Fachgebiet = '12001_SID' # This code is for Hausärzte, look up other codes here https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/getExpertiseAreaStructure 

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="KVWL_retrieval")
location = geolocator.geocode(location)

headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
data = '{"Latitude":' + str(location.latitude) + ',"Longitude":' + str(location.longitude) + ',"DocGender":"","DocNamePattern":"","ExpertiseAreaStructureId":"' + Fachgebiet + '","ApplicableQualificationId":"","SpecialServiceId":"","LanguageId":"","BarrierFreeAttributeFilter":{"ids":[]},"PageId":0,"PageSize":100}'
response = requests.post('https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/searchDocs', headers=headers, data=data)
r = json.loads(response.content)

df = pd.json_normalize(r['DoctorAbstracts']['DoctorAbstract'])

def get_doctor(id_nr):
    data = '{"Id":"' + id_nr + '"}'
    response = requests.post('https://www.kvwl.de/DocSearchService/DocSearchService/getDoctor', headers=headers, data=data)
    r = json.loads(response.content)
    time.sleep(2) # don't overload the site
    return pd.json_normalize(r)

df.join(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_doctor(x.Id).to_dict()), 1), rsuffix='_right')
```

The dataframe can be explored with `df.head()` or exported to csv or excel with `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` or `df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')`.

Comment: Hello Mr.Adriaansen, You have solved a huge problem for me just like that!! I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!! I have one question about the data that is extracted. For some of the fields the data was extracted as this  {0: '+49(521)63500'}  is this something normal and this need to be cleaned later or there is a way to read a clean value without flower bracters and 0: ?

Comment: Those fields are formatted as dictionaries. That is apparently how the json returns them. You should be able to extract the phone number with something like this: `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)`. Make sure to replace `column_name` with the name of the relevant column.